# Force Refreshing Embedded Google Gadget to Update With New Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-gadget

How do I force refresh a Google Gadget that's embedded in another website to update automatically and instantly when the Google spreadsheet/form that it's linked to updates with new data?

Answer (score 1):

You can't force it, but you can ask the gadget to automatically refresh every 5 minutes with:

```
 <UserPref name="_table_query_refresh_interval" display_name="Query Interval" default_value="300">
```

5 minutes == 300 seconds. Change it to whatever you want.